# Why when I create the migration, the UP and DOWN methods appear empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am starting to program with asp.net mvc 5 taking the course of udemy of Mosh-Hamedani, we are in the topic of ENTITY and when I create the migration the UP and DOWN methods appear empty. Some help? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare something like this in your DbContext:

```
public DbSet<YourModel> Items{ get; set; }
```

Comment: @JulioCheranthonyPeñaPérez i'm glad it works. For others to see it more clear that it works, you could mark it as best answer

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your DbContext has the DbSet specified, has caught me out multiple times. Apart from that, more code examples are needed for a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you did what @andyb952 said, and still not working go to the Migration folder an delete the 'SnapShot' then proceed with the migrations commands again.